# Third Order Coupled ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have these coupled equations based off Falkner-Skan:

f′′′=−f⋅f′′−(2m/(m+1))⋅(1−(f′)2)−(2/(m+1))⋅Ri⋅θcos(m/(m+1))

&

θ′′=−Pr⋅f⋅θ

With the BC's: f(0)=f′(0)=0 and θ(0)=1. f(5)=1 and θ(5)=0 (5 has been taken as the endpoint)

Where Pr, m and Ri are constants which can be assigned, f and θ are functions of η and the dash (') means derivative with respect to η.

I have a MATLAB file which solves this when Ri=0 by using the shooting method (as this is a BVP) and ODE45 but now it seems like that can no longer be used as easily because now they need to be solved simultaneously when Ri is not zero.

How can I solve this problem using MATLAB for the plots of f' and θ against η?

Comment: When asking a question, use the Latex coding for math parts.

Comment: Oh ok. How do I do this?

Comment: The basic Latex commands apply, such as \begin{something}...\end{something} or writing between two dollar symbols. If you are not familiar, just google "introduction to Latex", there are many good sources.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that.